# Convert Wavefront .obj to .off

Tags: geometry, file-format, file-conversion, wavefront

How can I convert a [Wavefront's .obj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) file to a [.off file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OFF_%28file_format%29) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the open source GUI software [Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/).

- `File` > `Import Mesh` (Ctrl-I)
- `File` > `Export Mesh As` and chose "Object file format (.off)"

Comment: If you prefer command line, meshlab is bundled with a command line version (meshlabserver) that can just do the same on a CLI:


`meshlabserver -i input.obj -o output.off `


(_eventually also performing some filtering by specifying a script file..._)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CLI, closed source, binary only, [meshconv](http://www.patrickmin.com/meshconv/)

```
chmod u+x meshconv
./meshconv input.obj -c off -o output.off
```

Howether the result seems to be a bit different from what I get in my answer using Meshlab because I could not load the resulting .off file in CGAL (the error look like [this one](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Unable-to-read-off-files-td4659156.html)).

Answer (score -1):

This should work for triangular meshes

```
def conv_obj(file):
    x = open(file)    
    k = 0
    while "\n" in x.readline():
        k += 1
    x = open(file)
    out = str()
    v = 0
    f = 0
    for i in range(k) :
        y = x.readline().split()
        if len(y) > 0 and y[0] == "v" :
            v += 1
            out += str(y[1]) + " " + str(y[2]) + " " + str(y[3]) + "\n"
        if len(y) > 0 and y[0] == "f" :
            f += 1
            out += "3 " + str(int(y[1])-1) + " " + str(int(y[2])-1) + " " + str(int(y[3])-1) + "\n"
    out1 = "OFF\n" + str(v) + " " + str(f) + " " + "0" + "\n" + out
    w = open(file.strip("obj") + "off", "w")
    w.write(out1)
    w.close()
    x.close()
    return "done"
```